# How to make clean url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-url

I want to create a clean url for my `blog.php` page I dont want to show the `blog.php` in address bar I want this type of url

```
http://www.webiste.com/title/how-to-make-dynamic-menu
```

But my existing url is like that

```
http://www.webiste.com/blog.php?title=how-to-make-dynamic-menu
```

I have read and attempt many code but didn't get the good result

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should write

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blog\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$ blog.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I guess i should explain what does this peace of code do.
Its a basic "if" statement.

You see mod_rewrite or "RewriteEngine" give us the option to take the original query, and if it matches a certain criteria (RewriteCond ) rewrite it to something else (RewriteRule).

Comment: i m using on localhost
my folder name is testing
and for testing i m using now static way below 

<a href='blog.php?name=how-to-make-dynamic-menu'> Titanic </a>

but now didn't worked yes 

i also create a .htaccess file 

copy and paste the code which you provide